# Getting WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I am trying to make a folder/directory inside **C:\Program Files** but due to insufficient  permission I am not able to make it.

**Python Code:**

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Program Files')
os.mkdir('New Folder')
```

**Error Encountered:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
   os.mkdir('New Folder')
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'New Folder'
```

**I also tried:**

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Program Files')
os.makedirs('New Folder')
```

**Error Encountered:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#21>", line 2, in <module>
        os.makedirs('santosh')
    File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'New Folder'
```

**How can I overcome this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run your python script with admin rights for the python process (\Program Files\Python\python.exe) ?

Comment: OK, and if you put your script in system32 folder and try to run it with a batch file who is executed with admin rights ?

Comment: I don't want to make a batch file. I just want to make through my own script

Comment: Yes, I understand. And, have you tried to set the entire path in the func args like `os.mkdir( 'C:\Porgram Files\FolderToCreate', 0755 );` ?

Comment: it's surprising ... but you are not alone. Many other python users have this problem. Maybe try changing the rights of the Program files folder and set full rights for your profile....

Comment: yeah I did it by accessing python in full administrator rights using ctypes module